# GTK Linux C Get Input from Entry Box via Button Widget

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I have a table that is filled with entry boxes, labels, and buttons.

Currently, if I compile the code, I can get input from a text box but only if the users presses the enter key, and the text only comes from the box they are currently typing in.

I would like to be able to get input from both text boxes when the "Login" button is pushed. I've tried using the same callback function that's used for enter key on the entry box, but GTK gives me an error.

If anyone could show me some code that would allow for me to get text from my entry boxes that are within tables (I know the method for retrieving data from tables and v/boxes is different) it would be greatly appreciated, as I can't seem to find it in any tutorials.

Will update w/working code.

Error when trying to attach status bar to table:

(Entry:5526): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_table_attach: assertion `child->parent == NULL' failed

(Entry:5526): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from `GtkTable' to`GtkStatusbar'

Comment: Getting values from entry boxes is the same no matter what container they are situated within.

Comment: Thanks James, so how would I do it? The enter_callback function does not work when a button calls it. Should it?

Comment: Don't change your question to a new question when someone gives you an answer to your original question. Accept the answer (if correct) and then post an entirely new question describing the problem you face and what you have done to overcome it but still require help with.

Comment: James, in the comments of the code of my original, unedited post I wrote "how would I add a statusbar to a table?". I already told you I'd accept your answer, but that question was included in the original one, so I'm going to give it a chance to be answered also.

Comment: In that case I vote your question down.

Comment: 1) Look at the title of your question. 2) How about you look at the documentation https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.7/GtkStatusbar.html#GtkStatusbar.description 3) The errors you're seeing regarding the statusbar are because when you add it to the table, when you have already added it to the vbox with `gtk_box_pack_start`.

Comment: Nope, sorry but you are wrong James, that has nothing to do with it. I was able to have this question answered on another board with very experienced C developers, but thanks again for trying. I'll put the working code up today wen I have some time.

Comment: No I am not wrong about adding the status bar to two different containers. First you added it to the vbox and then to the table. This is the exact cause of the `gtk_table_attach: assertion `child->parent == NULL' error message. However should you wish to enlighten me of my ignorance please post a link to the discussion you had with the very experienced C developers.

Answer (score 4):

Your callback function (named `callback`) needs to access both GtkEntry widgets in order to obtain their values. There are several ways this can be accomplished. Many GTK C programs use global variables, or global variables with file scope (ie a variable declared as `static` outside of any function within a file).

Remove your `entry1` and `entry2` variables near the top of the file before any functions:

```
static GtkWidget *entry1 = 0;
static GtkWidget *entry2 = 0;
```

And then modify the callback like so:

```
/* Our callback.
 * The data passed to this function is printed to stdout */
static void callback( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    const gchar *entry_text1;
    const gchar *entry_text2;

    g_print ("Hello again - %s was pressed\n", (char *) data);

    entry_text1 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (entry1));
    entry_text2 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (entry2));
    g_print ("Contents of entries:\n%s\n%s\n", entry_text1, entry_text2);
}
```

You should additionally make similar modifications to the `enter_callback` function, and don't forget to remove the `GtkWidget` pointers to both `GtkEntry` from `main`.

---

As an alternative to using (static) global variables, create a data structure to hold the entries:

```
typedef struct login_data
{
    GtkWidget *entry1;
    GtkWidget *entry2;
} login_data;
```

This then gets passed to the callback (rather than text string as before), and the callback changes like so:

```
static void callback( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    login_data* ld = (login_data*)data;
    const gchar *entry_text1;
    const gchar *entry_text2;

    entry_text1 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (ld->entry1));
    entry_text2 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (ld->entry2));
    g_print ("Contents of entries:\n%s\n%s\n", entry_text1, entry_text2);
}
```

The data structure is dynamically allocated to prevent it going out of scope (not strictly necessary in simple applications) and this is done before using `g_signal_connect` to connect the callback to the entries:

```
login_data* ld = g_malloc(sizeof(*ld));

// callback function to execute when login is clicked
g_signal_connect (LoginButton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (callback), (gpointer) ld);
```

Using this method, you must change all references to `entry1` and `entry2` to `ld->entry1` and `ld->entry2`. Lastly, before the program exits, you should call `g_free` on the dynamically allocated struct ie `g_free(ld)`.

BTW, for this program you don't need two separate callbacks, remove `enter_callback` and just use `callback` for both.

Comment: That's right James, worked perfectly 1st try! I'll accept this as an answer and thanks for your time. Would you mind also commenting on adding status bars to tables?

Comment: Nice James, I'll also try that. I edited the errors I'm receiving when trying to push a value onto my status bar.

Comment: It's been a while since I've written any GTK code so I would need to look at the documentation...